# Failed to connect to bus

Tags: dbus

So I have been trying to fix this for a couple of days. I found some solutions but they result in another problem:

```
Launcher helper exited with unknown exit code 1.
```

Every time I do something involving the `dbus` service. It starts giving the same error everywhere
[image: dbus error]

I first encountered the problem on trying: `netplan apply` and results in the same failed to connect to `dbus` as above 
[image]

After restarting the ubuntu console, the failed to connect to `dbus` error is gone until I run anything related to it.

How can I solve this? Without it throwing the launcher helper exit code again?

I'm using **WSL ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

The try output of `netplan` shows this: https://pastebin.com/pMuypudS

The output of `ps -ef | grep dbus: root`

```
27     9  0 16:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dbus
```

The output of `env | grep -i dbus: Nothing`

Comment: Did you do anything with python? Installed a new version, etc?

Comment: No I dont use python, but I could try to install it, same problem after installing it.

Comment: can you show `env | grep -i dbus` and `ps -ef | grep dbus`  https://askubuntu.com/posts/1295112/edit  edit your question for that.

Comment: Does *"running on windows 10"* mean WSL? if so, I wouldn't expect the dbus service to be running. What did you modify in order to start it?

Comment: Yes that means WSL, no modifactions

Comment: I just found another solution: sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start, that works and starts the dbus system succesfully, but now I get: 'Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1' again.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another solution: sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start, that works and starts the dbus system succesfully.

Comment: but..  stil getting this: 'Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1'